# Springboot Communication with S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

i have got a problem i can't resolve for some hours, so i decide to post it with the hope someone can help me there.
So basically i'm trying to connect my springboot to an s3 bucket i created on the AWS console manager and store some images i supply.
Here is my code java :

```
@Service
public class AmazonClient {
    private AmazonS3 s3client;

    @Value("${amazonProperties.endpointUrl}")
    private String endpointUrl;
    @Value("${amazonProperties.bucketName}")
    private String bucketName;
    @Value("${amazonProperties.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;
    @Value("${amazonProperties.secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;
    @Value("${amazonProperties.region}")
    private String region;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initializeAmazon() {
        System.out.println(this.accessKey+'\n'+this.secretKey+'\n'+Regions.fromName(this.region));
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(this.accessKey, this.secretKey);
        AmazonS3 amazonS3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
               .withRegion(Regions.fromName(region))
               .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
               .build();
       this.s3client = amazonS3Client;
       System.out.println(this.s3client);
    }
    private void uploadFileTos3bucket(String fileName, File file) {
        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file)
                .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
    }
    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) {

        String fileUrl = "";
        try {
            File file = convertMultiPartToFile(multipartFile);
            String fileName = generateFileName(multipartFile);
            fileUrl = endpointUrl + "/" + bucketName + "/" + fileName;
            uploadFileTos3bucket(fileName, file);
            file.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileUrl;
    }
}
```

Getting `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID: TDH3Q44GGPGGY2DD; S3 Extended Request ID: oQOOA9bu3bhoHNudJEOFkto1aXEjxKVfblnFWAJ2eJmFTG6mnKSHycHeQpbLP4kYITG9pQxNx9o=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: oQOOA9bu3bhoHNudJEOFkto1aXEjxKVfblnFWAJ2eJmFTG6mnKSHycHeQpbLP4kYITG9pQxNx9o=`
error when i call the upload method throught postman post request intercepted by controler...
The thing is i can't create an IAM user because i got a restricted AWS free 100$ account given by my school to work on. The permissions S3fullaccess is given to a predifined role assigned to current user. Consequently, aws CLI command `aws s3 ls` well list the bucket with accurate credential configuration. However, cant put any object in the bucket ....
I'm driving crazy because it seems like everything is working on the springboot part : the println(accesskey, secretkey and region are well fetched from my application.yml following:

```
amazonProperties:
  endpointUrl: https://s3.amazonaws.com
  accessKey: XXXXXX
  secretKey: XXXXXX
  bucketName: image-bucket-cpe
  region: us-east-1
```

).
If someone can help me, i will be forever beholden to him.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records" indicates the Access Key is incorrect (does not exists). How are you getting that Access Key? Is associated to your user?

Comment: Yes, the credentials are those of my user. The aws s3 ls works with the same credentials meaning they are the good ones. However when i use them on springboot they are not accepted. I know this is totally crazy

Comment: I came to the conclusion that i didn't have the access to write on the bucket. Howerver my role is have s3fullaccess permition meaning             "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"

Comment: If you debug your code, just before the S3 client initialization, the Access Key and Secret Access key are correct? (please check any blank spaces). Additionally, you are using Java SDK V1 but the recommended version is V2

Comment: Yes, like i said, throught the         `System.out.println(this.accessKey+'\n'+this.secretKey+'\n'+Regions.fromName(this.region));` i verified that the credentials are the good ones. However when using aws cli, in .aws/credentials i always put the aws_session_token or it gives me the same error when i delete it. I think this is the issue i'm facing. Do you know how can i add session token to AmazonS3 class ?

Comment: If you are using aws_session_token then it means you are using temporary credentials generated via STS. For Java SDK V1 you should use this class BasicSessionCredentials instead of BasicAWSCredentials. Here is an example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html  
Anyway, consider that when using tokens it has an expiration time. Also Java SDK V2 is the newest and recommended version.

Comment: Yeah, i switch to java sdk 2. Indeed i know there is an expiration time, however, i can't change it, i dont even have the write access to the ~/.aws/credentials of the aws lab and in it there is aws_an access_token! they are really making it hard, i hate them !

Comment: So it works using the token in BasicSessionCredentials (AwsSessionCredentials in Java SDK V2)?

Comment: Yeah ! works but actually i didnt implement the AwsSessionCredentials in java code, i better store it in the config files and what's cool with aws sdk v2 is that it automatically goes into ur files and takes it with the session token. That's works i'm so happy, thanks ! <3